# Trying to make a site mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a site that I'm trying to make mobile responsive but for some reason my right pan portion of the site suddenly appeared down. and the  header became the footer

it originally looked like this http://www.templatesbox.com/data/free.templates/images/web/full.preview/14032018641Yd.jpg

I messed with the Css while following a tutorial
here's the code

```
    /* CSS Document */
   body{padding:0px; margin:0px; background:#fff; color:#848484; font:11px/14px Tahoma,   Geneva, sans-serif}
   div, p, ul, h2, h3, h4, img, form, input, textarea{padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0}
  ul{list-style-type:none;}

   .clear {clear: both; margin: 0px; height:0}

   p a{ font:11px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#17afdb; text-decoration:none;}
   p a:hover{ color:#fe0600; text-decoration:none;}

  .headline{font:11px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#fe0600; font-weight:bold}

  #container{width:775px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; background:url(../images/b_body.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
  #incontainer{width:90%; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}


   /* HEADER */

 #headerPan{width:100%; height:337px; position:relative;          background:url(../images/header.png) 0 0 no-repeat; margin-bottom:10px}

  #headerPan img#logo{position:absolute; top:156px; left:434px}

   #headerPan ul.menu{position:absolute; top:28px; left:24px; width:95.84664536741214%; height:27px}
  #headerPan ul.menu li{float:left; height:27px;  margin-right:40px }
  #headerPan ul.menu li a{height:27px;  display:block; text-indent:-20000px; }
  #headerPan ul.menu li a:hover{height:27px; }

 #headerPan ul.menu li.b01 a{ width:13.25878594249201%;  background:url(../images/btn_1.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b01 a:hover{ width:13.25878594249201%;  background:url(../images/btn_1_over.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}

 #headerPan ul.menu li.b02 a{ width:11.34185303514377%;   background:url(../images/btn_2.png) 0 0  no-repeat; }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b02 a:hover{ width:11.34185303514377%;  background:url(../images/btn_2_over.png) 0 0  no-repeat;}

 #headerPan ul.menu li.b03 a{ width:8.626198083067093%;  background:url(../images/btn_3.png) 0 0  no-repeat; }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b03 a:hover{ width:8.626198083067093%;  background:url(../images/btn_3_over.png) 0 0  no-repeat;}

 #headerPan ul.menu li.b04 a{ width:18.05111821086262%;  background:url(../images/btn_4.png) 0 0  no-repeat; }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b04 a:hover{ width:18.05111821086262%;  background:url(../images/btn_4_over.png) 0 0  no-repeat;}

 #headerPan ul.menu li.b05{margin-right:0 }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b05 a{ width:11.82108626198083%;  background:url(../images/btn_5.png) 0 0  no-repeat; }
 #headerPan ul.menu li.b05 a:hover{ width:11.82108626198083%;  background:url(../images/btn_5_over.png) 0 0  no-repeat;}

  /* CONTENT */

 #contentPan{width:100%; position:relative; background:#fff; padding-top:20px;}
 #contentPanPages{padding:200px 0; text-align:center; background:#fff;}

 #leftPan{width:57.50798722044728&; float:left; margin:0 34px 0 2.236421725239617%;} 
 #rightPan{width:32.74760383386581%; float:left;} 

 #welcome{width:57.50798722044728%; margin:0 0 32px 0;}
 #welcome h2{width:57.50798722044728%; height:62px; background:url(../images/h_welcome.png) 0 0 no-repeat; margin-bottom:10px}
 #welcome img{float:left; margin-right:15px; max-width:100&;}

 #next_events{width:57.50798722044728%;}
 #next_events h2{width:57.50798722044728%; height:32px; background:url(../images/h_events.png) 0 0 no-repeat; margin-bottom:10px}
 #next_events img{float:left; margin-right:15px;}

 #history{width:32.74760383386581%; margin:0 0 0 0;}
 #history h2{width:32.74760383386581%; height:34px; background:url(../images/h_history.png) 0 0 no-repeat; margin-bottom:10px}
  #history p.maintext{margin-bottom: 12px; padding-bottom:12px; border-bottom:#a9a9a9 1px dotted }
  #history img{float:left; margin-right:10px;


 /* FOOTER */
 #footerPan{width:626px; height:63px; margin:0 auto; background:url(../images/b_footer.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
 #footerPan p{padding: 18px 0 0 0; font:10px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; color:#848484; text-align:center}
 #footerPan p span{ font:10px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#848484;}
 #footerPan p a{ font:10px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#848484; text-decoration:none; padding: 0 3px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; text-transform:uppercase }
 #footerPan p a:hover{ font:10px/14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; text-decoration:underline; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; text-transform:uppercase}
```

here's the html just in case

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sky Diving Club</title>

 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="pngfix.js"></script>

 </head>

   <body>

  <div id="container">

  <div id="incontainer">


  <div id="headerPan">

      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="b01"><a href="index.html" title="home">home</a></li>
      <li class="b02"><a href="about.html" title="about me">about us</a></li>
      <li class="b03"><a href="events.html" title="events">events</a></li>
      <li class="b04"><a href="gallery.html" title="photo gallery">photo gallery</a></li>
       <li class="b05"><a href="contacts.html" title="contacts">contacts</a></li>
     </ul> 

            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" name="logo" width="154" height="96" id="logo" />

 </div>
     <div id="contentPan">

      <div id="leftPan">

      <div id="welcome">
    <h2></h2>

   <img src="images/img_welcome.jpg" width="135" height="87" alt="" />

    <p><span class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer lobortis purus    vel </span><br />
      Nunc laoreet lacinia nunc. In volutpat sodales ipsum. Sed vestibulum. Integer in   ante. Mauris tincidunt, quam ac porta viverra, turpis sapien <a href="#">| more</a></p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>

   <div id="next_events">
   <h2></h2>

  <img src="images/img_events.jpg" width="135" height="87" alt="" />

  <p><span class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer lobortis purus vel   </span><br />
  Nunc laoreet lacinia nunc. In volutpat sodales ipsum. Sed vestibulum. Integer in ante. Mauris tincidunt, quam ac porta viverra, turpis sapien <a href="#">| more</a></p>
  <div class="clear" style="height:15px"></div>

    <p class="maintext">Mauris tincidunt, quam ac porta viverra, turpis sapien egestas mauris, et suscipit nulla orci sed odio. In ac sem Mauris tincidunt</p>

  </div>


  </div>


   <div id="rightPan">

   <div id="history">
   <h2></h2>
   <p class="maintext">Mauris tincidunt, quam ac porta viverra, turpis sapien egestas mauris, et suscipit nulla orci sed odio. In ac sem Mauris tincidunt, quam ac porta viverra</p>

  <img src="images/img_history.jpg" alt="" width="66" height="66" />
  <p><span class="headline">Donec lobortis </span><br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu </p>

  <div class="clear" style="height:15px"></div>

   <img src="images/img_history-03.jpg" alt="" width="66" height="66" />
   <p><span class="headline">Donec lobortis </span><br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu </p>

  <div class="clear" style="height:15px"></div>

   <img src="images/img_history-05.jpg" alt="" width="66" height="66" />

    <p><span class="headline">Donec lobortis </span><br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu </p>

     <div class="clear" style="height:15px"></div>



      </div>

   </div>

     <div class="clear" style="height:20px"></div>


     </div>
      <div id="footerPan">

      <p><a href="index.html">home</a> | <a href="about.html">about US</a> | <a     href="events.html">events</a> | <a href="gallery.html">gallery</a> | <a href="contacts.html">contacts</a><br/>
     <span>Copyright &copy; Sky Diving Club. All rights reserved.</span></p>

     </div>


     </div>


      </div>

      </body>
     </html>
```

any ideas?

Comment: In the CSS definition for `#leftPan`, there appears to be a typo in the units for `width` : `width:57.50798722044728&;`. Maybe you meant `width:57.50798722044728%;`? This is also the case for `#welcome img` `max-width`.

Comment: oh good eye, that did fixed the problem with the left pan appearing the bottom but i still have the problem of the header being where the footer is and the left pan seems to be squished with a wall of text

Comment: It is possible to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue? Since your external files are all relative URLs, it's [difficult to replicate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/44htD/).

Comment: here is it http://jsfiddle.net/Jnewguy/EvA76/5/

Comment: I am seeing the header at the top of the page. What do you mean it "became the footer"? http://jsfiddle.net/EvA76/6/

Comment: sorry I meant menu, the menu bar that was originally on top went to the bottom of the page instead

Comment: As far as I can tell, the menu is there in the header. But the `<a>` tags are intended way off screen: `text-indent:-20000px;`. http://jsfiddle.net/cnag7/1/

Comment: how about the right pan, it there a way making it cleaner? It wasn't originally squish

Comment: It seems that `#rightPan` is "squished" because of the width definition of `#history`: `width:32.74760383386581%;` http://jsfiddle.net/cnag7/2/ I strongly advise that you use a DOM inspector (like [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) or another development tool). It makes troubleshooting things like this much easier.